# Can we create an object in Java with out class like in js or python with random key and values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Like in other programing languages - python or JS, when we create a rest api specifically post for the request body we attract some JSON Object

EX:

url: .../employee (Post)

request body: {option: {filter: "suman"}}

In Python or JS we can just do request_body.option.filter and get the data

How can I achieve the same with Java ?
Do I need need to create a class for the reqeust_body and for option and make an instance object request_body

Comment: Java is not Python or JS. I would usually use a [`JSONObject`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html). Good luck!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch this should really be an answer of its own. You could reference wrapping, too, but it would probably be a waste of resources

Comment: @Elliott Frisch thanks for the comment 
If would be of great help if you look into the answer that I have written using JSONObject 

Also I Maven had a problem downloading the JSONObject JAR, I had to do this manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to parse the request body with JSONObject like below

```
@PostMapping("/customers")
    public List<Customer> getCustomerById(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> req) {

        // {option: {filter: "alf"}}
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(req);
        System.out.println(json.toString(4));
        System.out.println(json.getJSONObject("option").get("filter"));

        -----------------------
        -----------------------
        -----------------------



}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This depends with other framework elements you use in your application. For example if you bring Spring into the scene, you would be looking to use in built features like dependency injection and support for hibernate (JPA implementation), which depends on the concept of entities that are POJOs with extra annotations. So yes you would need to define entity classes and DTOs for those.